# JavaScript - NightWatch.js - Cucumber: How To handle returned values on step definitions

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

I am working in a project with NightwatchJS and Cucumber and I am having problem to work with values returned on the steps definition from custom commands.

my step

```
When('user click on save button', async () => {
    let referenceResponse = "referenceResponse"

    referenceResponse = await client.clickOnSaveDraftButtonTask();

    console.log("referenceResponse "+referenceResponse);
});
```

Custom command

```
//clickOnSaveDraftButtonTask.js

module.exports.command = async function () {
  const orderDetailsPage = this.page.orderDetailsPageObject();

  let responseData =  orderDetailsPage
    .clickOnSaveButton();
    console.log("responseDatas " + responseData);

    responseData.then((result) => {
      console.log("result " + result);
    });

    return responseDatas;
};
```

What is logged

```
When user click on save button
responseDatas [object Promise]
√ Passed [equal]: POST == POST
√ Passed [equal]: 201 == 201
√ Passed [strictEqual]: true === true
referenceResponse undefined
result {"reference": "ESXXXXXX"}
```

The thing is I need to recover the value on step definition so I would be able to validate result in another step.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the data you want to use in other steps in the world class. You can read more about the world class here https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/world.md